# How to fix rogue Firefox window?

Tags: firefox

I have a rogue Firefox Window which has no tab bar, and no orange Firefox menu button. It has no back button either, nor no home or bookmarks buttons. My other Firefox windows are fine. How can I right the bad window?

Sometimes in Google Chrome I encounter similar rogue windows. I tame them  by right-clicking and choosing 'show as tab'.

**Edit**: I want to keep the window open, I just want to reintegrate it into society.

Comment: On MS Windows: Alt+F4?

Answer (score 1):

As to why this happens? Usually the result of poor programming on the part of the site. These orphan windows without controls are usually created when a site is trying to load a pop-up or pop-under command and was either half-blocked by an extension or erroring in its HTML code.

Comment: Incorrect, latest versions of Firefox do NOT run each window and tab as a separate process. Currently, the latest version of Firefox only separates the plugin from the browser.

Firefox is eventually going to add this feature when the [Electrolysis project](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis/Firefox) is complete.

Comment: Ha right, caught me. I run so many beta versions i forget sometimes which features are actually published. Disregard that portion, but the root cause of these odd windows is the same. Something prevented a popup from rendering itself properly.

Comment: You should still remove that section of your comment. Spreading incorrect information is never a good idea, even if it is not relevant to the topic at hand.

Comment: original comment has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a reload of the window's contents, why not right-click, **View Page Info**, copy the URL and use it in a new tab/window?